# email host domain is active or not php/ lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, email-validation

Is there any library to check whether an email address has an active domain?

Actually, I want to validate an email address whose host domain must be active. I am using Laravel - Lumen micro framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the [MailboxValidator Laravel Email Validation Package](https://github.com/MailboxValidator/MailboxValidatorLaravel) in Github to validate email address using remote API. It connects to the mail server of MX records in real time to check if one account is valid or not. There are both Free and paid plan.

For more information, you can also visit https://www.mailboxvalidator.com/resources/articles/how-to-use-mailboxvalidator-laravel-email-validation-package-to-validate-email-during-registration/